# Company-mode complete custom matches not necessarily prefix

Tags: completion, company-mode

If I type character `a`, can `completion-at-point` be used to show possible matches from this list `a ɑ æ ɐ ɑ̃`, even without matching a prefix?

Comment: Does `C-h v completion-styles` help?

Comment: @phoxd: The answer is "yes".  I suspect you want something else, so please make your question more precise.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defconst sample-completions
  '(("a" "a" "ɑ" "æ" "ɐ" "ɑ̃") ("f" "o" "r")))

(defun company-sample-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))
  (case command
    (interactive (company-begin-backend 'company-sample-backend))
    (prefix (and (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
         (company-grab-symbol)))
    (candidates

      (dolist (element sample-completions)
        (let ((head (car element)))
          (message "%s -%s" head arg)
           (if (string= head arg)   
               (return element))))
     )))

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-sample-backend)
```

Tweaked from [here](https://sixty-north.com/blog/writing-the-simplest-emacs-company-mode-backend.html)

Enable `M-x company-mode` and `M-x fundamental-mode`, type `a` or `f` (the first element of list) and execute `company-complete` to get completion menu.

How would I enable it only inside quotations?